# Remove the DOM element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I remove the one element from DOM, Kindly refer my Image 1 (Actual UI) and Image 2(DOM element which need to be deleted).

NOTE:- All element in that `<td>` has same class name, so I have to be careful while removing specific element

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5QEv.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3heAu.jpg)

Comment: don't add images, paste your code as text. And if using `jquery`, select the element you want with the proper selector and use `.remove()`, what happens in the case that the element you want to remove has child elements? Should those be removed as well and if not, who becomes their parent?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and explain how to determine which element to remove

Comment: You'll need to be specific about what differentiates the element you're trying to remove, compared to the elements you don't want to remove.  Actual code -- in the question, not in comments -- is very much preferable to screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added two images which has UI and other one has DOM element which I need to remove. please help me. I tried using below code it didn't work for me -thiz.element.find('.s-panel-label-text').attr("id=Shipper Organization ID").remove();

Comment: @Kannan Assuming you are using the proper use of the `id` property, which is, it should ALWAYS be UNIQUE. Use the id as the selector: `$('#Shipper ORganization ID').remove();`

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your response, just now I tried this -  thiz.element.find('#Shipper ORganization ID').remove(); still its not removing from DOM, still I can able to see in the UI

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because you still haven't posted a [mcve]. I'll never understand why people do this. It takes far more effort to do the screenshot thing than it does to copy/paste code.

Answer (score 0):

it will be better to provide you code but try this
Give the `table` or `tr` id for example 
`<table id="#multColumnListTable">.....`
then in the jquery part(if you have jquery):

```
$('#multColumnListTable input:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
})
```

good luck.